# When are geodesics of $M$ also the shortest curves?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. A a curve $\gamma : I\rightarrow M$ is a geodesic if and only if $$\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}(\tau)}\dot{\gamma}(\tau) = \frac{d^2\gamma^\mu}{d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho}\frac{d\gamma^\nu}{d\tau} \frac{d\gamma^\rho}{d\tau} = 0\tag{1}$$

However, not every geodesic is also the shortest curve to travel from $p$ to $q$.

For an arbitrary Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions to assure that every geodesic $\gamma$ is also the shortest curve?

Comment: Is that subscript $\dot{\gamma(\tau)}$ supposed to be $\dot\gamma(\tau)\text{?}$ If it's intended to be $\dot{\gamma(\tau)}$ rather than $\dot\gamma(\tau),$ I'd say that's bad notation because it's visually challenging.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every geodesic from a point is minimising up to the [cut locus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) of the point. This is both necessary and sufficient - beyond the cut locus there always exist other shorter geodesics.

Comment: Add a remark: in the same homotopy class.

Comment: @gaoqiang, Your remark is incorrect: The shorter geodesic sometimes has to be in a different homotopy class, as for example for a flat torus.

Comment: @MikhailKatz  I mean, a geodesic is shortest in its homotopy class when there's no conjugate points.  I don't know whether it's correct in all cases. For manifolds with nonpositive curvatire, it should be right.  It's very hard to determine whether a geodesic is the shortest one among all curves since the topology may be very complicated.

Comment: @gaoqiang, if you consider only curves in the same homotopy type, that's the same as working in the universal cover of the manifold.  Then every geodesic is minimizing exactly up to the first conjugate point.  It is an if-and-only-if statement that does not depend on curvature restrictions or topology.

Comment: @MikhailKatz  Thank you for your comment. I remember there's a such a theorem, but not for sure since I always work with nonpositively curved space.